# Qt: make and install module on non-host platform

Tags: android, qt, qml

I am developing an app using a QML-based module (https://github.com/papyros/qml-material) on OSX and would like to test the app on Android and iOS.

How do I set up the qmake file so that the module gets properly installed for the Android and iOS platforms (or, for that matter, any other non-host platform which I have in my Qt distribution) on my host system?

In this specific case, just copying the module folder to e.g. `Qt/5.4/android_armv7/qml` does not work as the module needs to install some QtQuick Styles and other stuff elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. Running the platform-specific qmake alone wasn't working because this project contained two subprojects, each one with its own Makefile.

It was sufficient to (re-)run the platform-specific qmake for each subproject and for the main project prior to running `sudo make install`.

So the bottom line is, make sure that the Makefiles that qmake generates for subprojects are updated for your target platform.